# Search if a value exists in postgresql ltree

Tags: sql, postgresql, contains, ltree

I am trying to check if a particular value exists in a list of ltree column. For example path column contains values {1.2.270, 1.270.3, 1.302.270.70}. I am trying to find if the value 270 exists in any of these 3 paths. But it is not working if I am using IN or ANY keywords.

Comment: Please visit the help center, take the tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research - search SO for answers. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.30.6)

```sql
SELECT '{1.2.270, 1.270.3, 1.302.270.70}'::ltree[] ~ lquery('*.270.*')
```